# EF Change Database context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

i am creating a sort of data importer and I have to work from different databases/tables, depending on the source database I'm importing.

So I started creating a Model with EF for every type of database I have to work with.

Based on the application setting, I have to import data from a particular database.

So what I want to do is something like that:

```
var myDB; //the schema I need;
switch(DBType){
   case DBTypes.Application1:
          myDB = new APP1_Entities();
          break;
   case DBTypes.Application2:
          myDB = new APP1_Entities();
          break;
}
```

There is some way I can do this (or some kind of) with C# and EF?
Thanks for everyone!

Comment: Look into dependency injection.

Comment: How Dependency injection will help import process?

Comment: OP, what exactly you can't solve? You have to read data from database, using one of the contexts. What should be the output?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to solve this would be through dependency injection. This way the dependency is inverted and you are not "newing up" the context in the method.

```
public void DoSomething(DbContext context)
{
    myDb = context;

    //other logic here
}
```

This gives control of the method to the caller. For more information there are plenty of resources all over the web. 
MSDN documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323705(v=vs.100).aspx